# animation using drawRRect in flutter

Tags: animation, flutter, custom-painting

`Flutter- Animation` using rounded rectangle method  in custom painter

I am trying to create an animation in custom painter while drawing rectangle using rounded rectangle method I don't know to animate

Comment: use `repaint` parameter passed to [CustomPainter](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter/CustomPainter.html) constructor

Comment: Please be more specific on your questions, if you don't know how to Animate first google for a good tutorial. And then just ask about an specific error or situation. Also post some code of what you have achieved so far.